# Merging an Old MySQL dbase with a new dbase> There are some new tables in the new one..?

Tags: mysql, database, import, merge

What is the best method for doing this?  Import>

If I simply do a dump of the old one, MySQL database, and import into the "new database" that is up and running on a new server. Will new tables in the new database interfere, or will old data/tables that match...just simply import and populate into the new database?

am I going about this in the correct way?

Comment: Are you doing this programmatically or with a tool like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I'll be using phpmyadmin, I only have one machine instance where I need to do the import.

Answer (score 0):

I would initially back up both the old and new databases using `mysqldump` or by exporting the databases via `phpmyadmin`.

After that you can then import the old database dump into the new database, which should leave the existing "new" tables and add the tables from your old database. Remember, if anything goes wrong you'll always have your backups handy!

P.S. The only time your tables *"might"* interfere is when you have two tables with the same name but different structures, so be careful with that!

Comment: Great, thank you!  that's what I was looking for, structures.

Comment: Thanks a million for the advice!  the import worked (partially) I ended up having to import some tables manually.  Thought overall it worked great.  thanks again!!